# application.visible = true Does Not Work

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I need some help. I have an Access 2007 database that creates an Excel file. I do hide the Excel file in the beginning using xl.Visible = True... I can make a code change and it will work while I have Access open, but as soon as I close Access and re-open the same database the code does not work anymore. I know my code is working because I had used message boxes around the code and those were firing. It is essential for the Excel file to be showing on top of the Access database.

I have tried ActivateMicrosoftApp, ActiveWindow, GoTo, and WindowState... All have no effect...

We are using Access 2007 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do hide the Excel file right after setting the object using xl.Visible = False.

Comment: Any hidden Excel instances visible in Task Manager?

Comment: No extra instances of Excel are visible in the Task Manager. I should add that this is a multi-user (100+ users) database. I realize that Access was not made for this kind of use. We are in the process of migrating this database over to MySQL, but in the meantime we need this to be working correctly.

Comment: I know this sounds simple and that you have tried several methods independently, but did you try minimizing the access window, setting xl visible , activating the xl workbook , and then maximizing the excel window ? sometimes xl hangs and performing another action like maximizing will get it to appear.

Comment: Just did try that... I added "xl.WindowState = xlNormal" right after my "xl.Visible = True" statement. The code will work until I close out of my database and reopen it or try to create the ACCDE, then the code fails again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this done by doing the following:

xl.Visible = True
xl.WindowState = xlMaximized <--- optional statement
AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"

Thank you everyone for your responses. Hopefully this will save someone from the major headache that I had.

Comment: 'code' xl.Visible = True xl.WindowState = xlMaximized <--- optional statement AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"